# Exception IllegalThreadStateException thrown even though isAlive() returns false

Tags: java, multithreading

I am writing some code with threads and I have the following problem. This is the code where the exception occurs:

```
if (veh != null && wantedRegistrations.contains(veh.getRegistration())) {
    veh.setLeavingTrue();
    if(!veh.isAlive()) {
        veh.start();
    }
}
```

So I debugged this, and isAlive() returns false, if block is entered and then IllegalThreadStateException is thrown in Thread.java here:

```
if (threadStatus != 0)
    throw new IllegalThreadStateException();
```

and in the comment above it says:

> A zero status value corresponds to state "NEW".

threadStatus is always 2 when the exception is thrown, which means that it is in BLOCKED state. Okay, so this is confusing because I thought that isAlive() returns false if the thread is NEW or TERMINATED. I can't post the entire code because there is a lot of it, but I am interested in this behaviour of isAlive() method.

Comment: Nope, it is a JavaFX application.

Comment: Re, "And yes, the thread was started before..."  There's your problem. A `Thread` instance can only be started one time.

Comment: This question is somewhat unanswerable in its current state. The first code block seems to suggest that `veh` is an object that extends `Thread`, although `veh` could be an object that implements `Runnable` and has a custom `start()` method. The point is, a possible answer-er can spend time writing an answer on assumptions that may end up being incorrect, in which case they've wasted their time. TLDR: You need to [edit] your question to include a [mcve], that is - give us a minimal amount of your code, that compiles, and will reproduce, exactly, the outcome you are experiencing.

Comment: @SolomonSlow Yeah, you are right. You can post an answer.

Comment: I don't think it's a duplicate, since my situation is more detailed. I now learned that thread that has been started before will stay in BLOCKED state after execution.

Comment: Not answering your direct question, but the approach seems backwards.  A `veh` is constructed, then later it's decided if it should be started.  The opposite may be easier, where the code decides if some processing needs done, and if yes, then create 'veh` and start it immediately.

Comment: @AndrewS It is a project for a course at uni that tests my multithreading skills. It is like a garage simulator, where each car is a thread that moves on it's own in a matrix. I need to park the car so it needs to be started when it enters the garage, but if a police car drives by and the plates of the parked car are wanted, then that car needs to exit the garage after the police car so it needs to be started again, or never stopped in the first place. It doesn't do anything practical, it's just complicated because it needs to be complicated.

Comment: @Nebeski *"... thread that has been started before will stay in BLOCKED state after execution."* - I don't think this is correct. A thread should be in the `TERMINATED` state after execution, unless you're using something like a thread pool or `ExecutorService`. I think you're seeing the state of your main thread where the `IllegalThreadStateException` is being caught. Putting `System.out.println(veh.getState().toString());` in your conditional, before `veh.start();` might shed some light.

Comment: @JonnyHenly You are right, it is terminated.

Comment: @Nebeski you should look into the [`ExecutorService`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) interface and the classes that implement it, such as [`ThreadPoolExecutor`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html). Instead of each car being a thread, have a set number of threads that execute tasks as they arise. Such as entering the garage and parking a car, exiting the garage, ... The threads in the pool won't reach the terminate state, they can sleep until notified of a new garage task or busy wait.

Comment: @Nebeski The garage tasks would just need to implement [`Runnable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Runnable.html), i.e. override `public void run() { /* garage task stuff */ }`.

Comment: @JonnyHenly I use ExecutorService and Runnables for entering the garage, and some other things, but I think that making each Vehicle a thread is more intuitive. If a car has another car infront of it, it will wait on it and the other car will notify when it moves. There is many other requests in the project, that seem better implemented with Thread vehicles, at least to me.

Answer (score 1):

If you start a thread and use `isAlive()` too soon, you can get `false`, as the thread is still starting. On the other hand, if you call `start()` on a thread that is already started, it will throw an `IlegalThreadStateException`.

Comment: isAlive() is not used too soon, at least several seconds pass before that. And yes, thread was started before. I am still trying to debug it, and it seems to me the thread exits run() just fine but somehow it stays blocked.